# What is meant by supported on prime numbers in this context?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, sieve-theory

I am reading  Sieve - Theory from following lecture notes of Prof. Zeev Rudnick: [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html) .

I am studying lecture 11 page 6.

But I think you will be able to understand the question without looking at that page:

Text of the paragraph : Section 2 ( Lower Bounds)

To obtain lower bounds we will need more information about our multiplicative function in particular we will need some information about it's behavior on the prime numbers. Let $\omega$ be a non-negative multiplicative function supported on square frees.

> Can you please tell what exactly author means by $\omega$ being supported on square frees?

Thanks!

Comment: The support of a function is usually the set where it takes non-zero values, but sometimes people say $f$ is supported on $X$ if $f$ is zero outside of $X$, even though it may take zero values on $X$ too.

Comment: The support of a function $f$ is the set $\{ x : f(x) \neq 0 \}$. Hence "supported on squarefree numbers" means that your function does not vanish exactly on squarefree numbers

Comment: Rudnick defines another function $\omega(n)$ already on page $2$. There it was zero on prime powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is [*supported*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) on $A \subseteq X$ if $f(a) \ne 0$ for all $a \in A$. The *support* of $f$ is the largest set on which $f$ is supported.

Comment: ... the *smallest* set ...

Comment: @MartinR Have I gone mad? The smallest set on which $f$ is supported is $\emptyset$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $f$ is “supported on $A$” if $f(a) = 0$ for all $a \notin A$.

Comment: Huh. I can't actually find anything to confirm or refute that "is supported on" is usually taken to mean what I would call "is *at most* supported on". Do you have a source?